# Не работает запрос из java в mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, исключения

Есть запрос     public final static String

```
SELECT_TEACHER_WHERE_WEEK_DAY_AND_CLASSROOM = "SELECT *\n" +
            "FROM teacher\n" +
            "JOIN teacher_m2m_subject AS ts\n" +
            "ON id = ts.t_id\n" +
            "JOIN subject AS s\n" +
            "ON ts.s_id = s.id\n" +
            "JOIN subject_m2m_classroom AS sc\n" +
            "ON s.id = sc.s_id\n" +
            "JOIN classroom AS c\n" +
            "ON c.id=sc.c_id" +
            "WHERE week_day=? AND room=?";
```

Метод в котором он вызывается:

```
@Override
    public List<Teacher> findAll(String weekDay, String classroom) {
        List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection cn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            cn = DatabaseUtil.getInstance().getConnection();
            //ps = cn.createStatement();
            ps = cn.prepareStatement(SELECT_TEACHER_WHERE_WEEK_DAY_AND_CLASSROOM);
            ps.setString(1, weekDay);
            ps.setString(2, classroom);
            ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()){
                teachers.add(getTeacherFromRs(resultSet));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(cn);
        }
        return teachers;
    }
```

Прилетает exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'week_day='Понедельник' AND room='318а'' at line 10
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at by.runets.simpleapp.dao.impl.TeacherDAO.findAll(TeacherDAO.java:38)
    at by.runets.simpleApp.dao.DaoTest.testDao(DaoTest.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Comment: " ...ON id = ts.t_id\n" 
Думаю здесь тоже ошибка, т.к ид двусмысленный.
Напишите "... ON teacher.id = ts.t_id\n"
А лучше проверить запрос в бд и найти ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

вы забыли пробел (или перевод строки) перед `WHERE`